# Populate three columns when form is saved

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following form which should be completed BEFORE the data is submitted to the sheet:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/xsXxd7z.jpg]

I am trying to code it so upon completion of the form and when the save button is clicked, it will find the first empty cell in column A and copy down the formula from above, I have managed to do this successfully but now I want to tab into column B and copy down the formula from above like before.

THEN tab into column C and enter the data in order from the form I have created into adjacent cells.

Here is my code but I really am in the dark here!

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Dim irow As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("Master Data")

NextFree = Range("A10:A" & Rows.Count).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Row
Range("A" & NextFree).Select

' Copy formula from cell above
    Dim oCell As Range
        For Each oCell In Selection
            If (oCell.Value = "") Then
            oCell.Offset(-1, 0).Copy Destination:=oCell
            End If
        Next oCell

End Sub

' Move to adjacent cell
    Sub MoveOver()
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Select
    End Sub


'Insert data into cells
Sub LastRow()
.Offset(1, 0) = ComboBox1.Text
.Offset(1, 1) = TextBox1.Value
.Offset(1, 2) = TextBox2.Value
.Offset(1, 3) = TextBox3.Value
.Offset(1, 4) = TextBox4.Value
.Offset(1, 5) = TextBox5.Value
.Offset(1, 6) = TextBox6.Value

End Sub
```

Comment: I am not sure what this has to do with the picture....are you not just trying to copy the next empty row with the cells above? I don't see a relationship with the UserForm.

Comment: Ok.. columns A+B have a formula in that are not included on the form. I have successfully managed to find the empty cell at the end of column A and copy it down. The last line of code at this point is   "Next oCell".. HOWEVER, i can't get it to move into the adjacent column B and perform the same action. it is then in column C where I want the form to start.

Comment: Ok that is fantastic and does exactly what I need for columns A and B, now the final part of my problem is getting the data from the form into the adjacent columns, so for example DateTextBox into column C, ProjectTextBox, into column D etc. Thanks for your assistance!

Comment: Code has been edited, you will have to test the offsets to see if they are going to the correct cells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could it be something like this you are looking for?

```
Dim lstRw As Long
lstRw = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Range("A" & lstRw & ":B" & lstRw).Copy Range("A" & lstRw + 1)
```

You can keep it in the same sub, such as

```
Dim lstRw As Long
Dim Rng As Range
lstRw = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
Set Rng = Range("A" & lstRw + 1)
Range("A" & lstRw & ":B" & lstRw).Copy Range("A" & lstRw + 1)
With Rng
    .Offset(, 2) = ComboBox1.Text
    .Offset(, 3) = TextBox1.Value
    .Offset(, 4) = TextBox2.Value
    .Offset(, 5) = TextBox3.Value
    .Offset(, 6) = TextBox4.Value
    .Offset(, 7) = TextBox5.Value
    .Offset(, 8) = TextBox6.Value
End With
```

Comment: AGAIN that is fantastic!" I have one final question as I am really struggling to get the syntax right, I have another formula that will appear after that range in Column J which I want to copy down, then 4 more data fields to continue into Column K,L,M,N,   So basically I want to go back to step one but for column J and then repeat step 2 for K.L,M,N... Thanks again for your help and your patience!!

Comment: You can copy the same line then just change the column letters to what you require on each new line

Comment: That works perfectly! Thank you for your assistance.